# C++/CLI - Textbox HideCaret - hide blinking cursor

Tags: winforms, textbox, c++-cli, clr

Is there any method to use `HideCaret()`.... or in general, just achieve something like described here:

[Prevent Blinking Cursor in Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601255/prevent-blinking-cursor-in-textbox)

**but in a Managed C++ (clr)** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in C++/CLI, just call HideCaret directly, no need for `DllImport`.

```
#include <windows.h>

System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textbox1;

HideCaret((HWND)textbox1->Handle.ToPointer());
```