# C# Prevent Blinking Cursor in Textbox, Solution not Working

Tags: c#, winforms, caret

I have found [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601255/prevent-blinking-cursor-in-textbox) pages describing how to prevent the blinking caret.  Looks simple enough.

```
[DllImport("user32")]
public static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

private void OnFocusEnterSpecificTextbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ HideCaret(SpecificTextbox.Handle); }
```

It's not working.  When I click on the Textbox, there's the caret.  I can breakpoint and see that I am hitting that code.

What boneheaded mistake am I making?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by hiding the caret? Did you check the return value from `HideCaret` (and `GetLastError`)?

Comment: I appreciate the quick reply.

When I click my Run button, the focus jumps to one of the read-only textboxes on my form, and even highlights the text.  I find that jarring, and I expect my users would, too.

I'm getting a false return from HideCaret.  Trying to figure out how to GetLastError, but my first stab caused an exception.  It's late.  I'll return to this tomorrow.

Comment: Try something like this. `textBox1.GotFocus += (s1, e1) => { HideCaret(textBox1.Handle); };`

Comment: Which event are you actually using? The method name is a bit ambiguous. You need to use `GotFocus`, not `Enter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (VS 2008 on Windows 7):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.GotFocus += new EventHandler(textBox1_GotFocus);
    }


    void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HideCaret(textBox1.Handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I got sucked in through Visual Studio surfacing Enter, but not GotFocus.  I need to research that for the subtle differences.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another way to stop blinking cursor in `TextBox`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.GotFocus += (s1, e1) => { HideCaret(textBox1.Handle); };
    }
}
```